# Shell extension installer closes explorer on uninstall

Tags: c#, windows-installer, windows-shell

I have created a C# app with an installer. The app needed a shell extension and after learning of the pitfalls of creating a shell extension with managed code I decided to go the route of using C++ for the shell extension. I successfully got the shell extension working with the existing code and installer. To register the C++ extension I have set the Register property to vsdrpCOMSelfRegister for the extension Primary output. When I tested the uninstall process I get a window that pops up asking me to kill explorer so the file can be removed.

Is there a setting in the installer project that would set the DLL to be removed after a restart instead of killing explorer? Or should I switch to a different installer like Inno Setup?